# Django Tenants superuser creation

Tags: django, multi-tenant

When we create a superuser per scheme via

```
./manage.py create_tenant_superuser --username=admin2 --schema=client2
```

The created super user can also login to "public" schema's admin page as well as other schema's admin pages.
While it can NOT edit other tenants' data it can modify the other super tenants information such as password's created under other schemas.

So is this the expected behavior?

should each tenant  have their own ,fully isolated admin page under `/Admin`?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more informations about your project - specifically about in which area/areas you use the auth apps. All tenants should have their own admin domain, since each uses a different scheme.
Put this in shared-apps and tenant-apps too:

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

If this dont work, please give more Details.